# Controlador en laravel que devuelva una consulta y se pueda aplicar a múltiples vistas

Tags: php, laravel-5, mvc, controller

Hola amigos soy nuevo en laravel estoy desarrollando en la versión 5.5 y tengo el siguiente inconveniente tengo un controlador que me devuelve un listado de países que consulta en la base de datos y luego los muestro en un select todo eso esta funcionando correctamente pero con una única vista si quiero que se muestre en todas las vistas como puedo agregarlo a todas las rutas.

Comment: mas que todo seria como pasar la variable a cualquier vista ya que actualmente para que tome la variable que contiene los datos me toca devolver el view junto con la variable desde el método del controlador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para estos casos Laravel tiene pensado los "view composer" desde Providers/AppServiceProvider en su funcion Boot por ejemplo :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Modelo\Pais;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        //Mandando todos los paises a todas las vistas existentes
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
                $paises= Pais::all();
                $view->with(compact('paises'));
        });

        //Mandando los paises solo a las vistas que empiezen por frontend. o auth.
        view()->composer(['frontend.','auth.'], function ($view) {
                $paises= Pais::all();
                $view->with(compact('paises'));
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: me funciono pero como indicas desde el Providers/AppServiceProvider por que intente crear un Provider propio y no funciono a pesar de que lo registre en config/app.php

Comment: puedes leer un poco mas sobre como funcionan los composer aqui https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers

Answer (score 0):

Buenas noches, una opción es hacer un controlador base, y que de ese controlador hereden los otros controladores, despues en el constructor de ese controlador podes hacer algo como:

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //its just a dummy data object.
        $paises = Pais::all();

       // Sharing is caring
       View::share('paises', $paises);
    }
}
```

Comment: Route::get('index', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('login', function () {
    return view('login');
});

yo devuelvo las rutas de esa forma como agregaria dicho controlador a esas rutas.

Comment: Tenes que crear un controlador del cual herede el controlador que estas usando

Tus controladores deberian estar declarados como:

class FooController extends BaseController

y cuando retornes la vista desde los controladores vas a tener disponible la variable $paises

Comment: y retornar los view desde esos controladores y no desde el archivo de rutas cierto..?

Comment: Exacto, tus rutas deberian llamar a metodos de controladores

Route::get('index', 'FooController@barmetodo');